# Discrete Math Help

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Please help with these 2:

For sets $A, B, C$, prove or disprove (with a counterexample)
the following: If $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq C$, then $A \subseteq C$.

and

Using Venn diagrams, investigate the truth or falsity of each
of the following, for sets $A, B, C$:

a) $A\cup  (B \cap C) = (A\cup  B) \cap (A \cup C)$

b) $A − (B \cup C) = (A − B) \cap (A − C)$

c) $A \cup (B \cup C) = (A \cup B) \cup C$

Comment: The first one is the transition property of proper subsets which you can actually prove quite easily.

Comment: Since you're new, I'd like to give you some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are**. That way, people won't tell you stuff you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: Many of the connectives are missing in your question (at least in my view).  It makes it impossible to answer the question.  For example, in the second paragraph I see "If $A \subseteq B, B\ C,$ then $A \ C$.  I can guess what they should be,  but in the one about Venn diagrams you have lower case letters sprinkled in and I can't even guess.

Comment: I’ve made the best guess that I can about the missing symbols in the original post; I’m moderately confident about (a) and (b), but (c) is frankly a bit of a guess.

Answer (score 1):

I will walk you through the first proof.

First, what does it mean to be a subset? $A \subseteq B$ iff $\forall x (x \in A \implies x \in B)$.  So to prove that $A \subseteq C$ what we want to do is take an arbitrary element in $A$ and then show that is also an element of $C$.

So, to begin, let $x \in A$ be arbitrary.  We want to try and force this $x$ into $C$.  This will finish the proof, since we have chosen $x$ arbitrarily and so this is saying **for any** $x$ we pick in $A$, that $x$ is also in $C$ (this is exactly what the definition above is saying).  But we have no relation between $A$ and $C$ to begin with, we must create a relation.  But we do know (by assumption) that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq C$.

What does this tell us? Since $x \in A$ and $A \subseteq B$ by definition of subset we have that $x \in$ __ . Now we have gotten one step closer to our goal.  What else do we know?  That $B \subseteq C$.  What can we do with this? (This is just like the previous line, I'll let you fill this in)... Then we end up with $x \in C$ (as we wanted to show) and since $x$ was an arbitrary element of $A$ we have that $\forall x (x \in A \implies x \in C)$ i.e. that $A \subseteq C$.

Maybe you can fill in the missing parts (I didn't want to give everything away, or else it's no fun!)  I'm not sure what your second questions are asking, maybe you can edit them and be more clear.  If you need some more hints for the first part, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Venn diagram for (a):

[image]

In the left diagram, $A$ is represented by horizontal hatching, $B\cap C$ is represented by vertical hatching, so the union of the two, $A\cup(B\cap C)$, is anything with any shading at all.

In the right diagram, $A\cup B$ has horizontal hatching, $A\cup C$ has vertical hatching, so their intersection, $(A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$, is any region with both horizontal and vertical hatching.

Compare the two; they're the same, so $A\cup(B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$.